# R - Appending multiple level 2 elements to each level 1 element of a list by name

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation, purrr

I have a list called `master`, which contains three IDs:

```
master = list(p1 = list(id = 'abc'), p2 = list(id = 'def'), p3 = list(id = 'ghi'))
str(master)
List of 3
 $ p1:List of 1
  ..$ id: chr "abc"
 $ p2:List of 1
  ..$ id: chr "def"
 $ p3:List of 1
  ..$ id: chr "ghi"
```

To each level 1 element of this list, I would like to append the corresponding value and radius elements from the `val` and `rad` lists:

```
val = list(p1 = list(value = 5), p3 = list(value = 8))
str(val)
List of 2
 $ p1:List of 1
  ..$ value: num 5
 $ p3:List of 1
  ..$ value: num 8

rad = list(p1 = list(radius = 2), p2 = list(radius = 10))
str(rad)
List of 2
 $ p1:List of 1
  ..$ radius: num 2
 $ p2:List of 1
  ..$ radius: num 10
```

I have to be careful to match the elements by name because `val` and `rad` do not have the same structure as `master`, i.e. `val` is missing a slot for `p2` and `rad` is missing a slot for `p3`.

I can use the following to partially achieve the desired result:

```
master_final = lapply(X=names(master),function(x, master, val, rad) c(master[[x]], val[[x]], rad[[x]]), master, val, rad)
str(master_final)
List of 3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ id    : chr "abc"
  ..$ value : num 5
  ..$ radius: num 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ id    : chr "def"
  ..$ radius: num 10
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ id   : chr "ghi"
  ..$ value: num 8
```

But I would like each element of the resulting list to have the same structure, i.e. an `id`, `value` and `radius` slot. I am not sure how to do this in a way that generalises to any number of lists? I don't like having to write `[[x]]` for each list in the `lapply` function: `function(x, master, val, rad) c(master[[x]], val[[x]], rad[[x]])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- list(master, rad, val) %>%
          transpose %>% 
          map(flatten)

str(out)
#List of 3
# $ p1:List of 3
#  ..$ id    : chr "abc"
#  ..$ radius: num 2
#  ..$ value : num 5
# $ p2:List of 2
#  ..$ id    : chr "def"
#  ..$ radius: num 10
# $ p3:List of 2
#  ..$ id   : chr "ghi"
#  ..$ value: num 8
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I like the simplicity of your solution. I didn't think to try transpose. But I have edited the desired output in my post slightly - I require each element of the resulting list to have the same structure, i.e. a list comprising of elements `id`, `value` and `radius`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @user51462. Wouldn't `list(master, val, rad) %>% transpose %>% map(flatten)` get the desired result?

Comment: Unfortunately not, e.g. the second element `p2` has structure `list(id = "def", radius = 10)` instead of `list(id = "def", value = NULL, radius = 10)`.

Comment: @user51462. Okay, I was checking your `master_final` which is not updated

Comment: Ah sorry, I was not sure how to derive the result I needed so wasn't able to update it.

Comment: @user51462. If you are okay with `NA`, then `list(master, val, rad) %>% transpose %>% map_dfr(~ flatten(.x) %>% as_tibble, .id = 'grp') %>% split(.$grp) %>% map(~ .x %>% select(-grp) %>% flatten)`

Comment: Thank you! But some values in my list are of class `function` (stored in a nested list structure like `list(formals (pairlist [2]), body (language), environment (environment [1345]))`, the brackets contain the class and size of the corresponding element). These values cause `as_tibble` to complain that `All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects: * Column 'value' is function`. `as.data.frame` and `data.frame` are similarly thrown off by these values. Is there a way to keep them nested during the creation of the tibble?

Comment: @user51462. i would say that it is better to have the reproducible example that mimics all those features/behaviors in the original dataset because people answer it based on a pattern they find.  Here, by looking at your comments below each of the answers, I see that none of the answer really helped. you much.  Do you think that it would be a waste of time for you and others as well (not saying in a bad way though)

Comment: I totally agree @akrun, my apologies! I hadn't realised that I would run into that problem when I had posted and I was trying to provide a minimal working example. I ended up using a variation of your solution, so I've marked it as the accepted answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user51462. It was not to criticize you.  Just to point out that your time is also precious.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to convert the lists to dataframe and do a `merge` based on list name. We can then `split` the dataframe based on `list_name`.

```
df1 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE, by = "ind"), 
                     list(stack(master), stack(val),stack(rad)))

names(df1) <- c("list_name", "id", "value", "radius")
lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$list_name), as.list)


#$p1
#$p1$id
#[1] "abc"
#$p1$value
#[1] 5
#$p1$radius
#[1] 2


#$p2
#$p2$id
#[1] "def"
#$p2$value
#[1] NA
#$p2$radius
#[1] 10


#$p3
#$p3$id
#[1] "ghi"
#$p3$value
#[1] 8
#$p3$radius
#[1] NA
```

This keeps `NA` values in the list as it is, if we want to remove them the code becomes a bit ugly.

```
lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$list_name), function(x) 
     {inds <- !is.na(x); as.list(setNames(x[inds], names(x)[inds]))})
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, the end result is a dataframe so I would have just used the first line of your solution since it would really simplify things, but the actual `master` list is nested and ragged so stack complains `Error in stack.default(ps) : at least one vector element is required` and `arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You could first group all your lists in `L` and run

```
L = list(master,val,rad)
lapply(names(master),function(x) unlist(lapply(L,"[[",x)))
[[1]]
    id  value radius 
 "abc"    "5"    "2" 

[[2]]
    id radius 
 "def"   "10" 

[[3]]
   id value 
"ghi"   "8"
```

Comment: Probably you could make use of the `recursive = FALSE` if the OP intends to have a `list` structure `lapply(names(master),function(x) unlist(lapply(L, `[[`, x), recursive = FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks @boski, I like this solution but I have edited the desired output in my post. I had forgotten to mention that I would like each element of the resulting list to have an `id`, `value` and `radius` element, is there a way to do that?